# How does Arduino XBee avoids using the serial I/O port?

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee

I have two Arduinos and two XBee modules. The modules are just mounted directly on to the Arduino board. One Arduino is sending information and another Arduino is receiving information and meanwhile listening to command from the computer it connects to. I just run the XBee code via the serial port, and it runs properly.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    byte x = Serial.read();
    if (x != 255)
        Serial.println(x);
}
```

However, if the code is changed to

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial xbee(2,3);
```

and change the Serial to XBee then everything doesn't work. I do not know why. Because I should avoid using the Serial as the serial port is communicating with C code on my computer. So I am willing to use another port to listen via the XBee. There may be some I/O port conflicts on Rx/Tx, but my Arduino doesn't connect to anything else except XBee.

The setup is like this:

| XBee|     <<---------->>  XBee

Arduino |||||||||||||||||| Arduino  <<---------->> computer C

How do I use `SoftwareSerial`?

Answer (score 1):

I have hacked Libelium's XBee shield to reroute the pin 1/0 of the board to 2/3, where I used a `SoftwareSerial` connection. But that change I made is permanent!

Basically what I've done is:

[image: Picture of the hack]
<sub>(source: [m0g.net](http://m0g.net/stuff/LibeliumXBeeShieldHacked.jpeg))</sub>

- Solder two wires on pad next to the 0 and 1 pins
- Solder the other end of the two wires on the central pin of the three pins jumper `XBEE/USB` (the one that is wired to the XBee).

But you can make it not permanent:

- By using a male-female [jumper wire](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718182018/http://hackspark.fr/fr/male-female-jumper-wires-125mm-50pcs.html), so you can wire the middle pins to the 2/3 pins.

To be sure about your connections, don't hesitate to double check the PCB and the schematic:

- http://www.libelium.com/squidbee/index.php?title=See_Schematics

Also, to be able to use that shield without any hack, you'd better use an [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/leonardo) which features an [ATmega32U4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/atmega32u4) that has two *distinct* serial ports: one for USB, another for pins 1/0.

Finally, if you do the permanent hack or use the Leonardo, you'll have to create a [sketch](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) that makes the Arduino act as a bridge between USB and the XBee when you'll need reflashing the XBee configuration using X-CTU (or xbee-comm or moltosenso).

N.B.: about the software serial, you just have to take the example from [the official documentation of Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial), for example.:

```
def setup():
    SoftwareSerial SwSerial(10, 11);

    SwSerial.begin(9600);
    SwSerial.write(42);
    while (SwSerial.available())
        SwSerial.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

The XBee modules expect port 0 and 1 as the serial connection. Here I am assuming that the actual XBee transceiver is plugged into a [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields), and the shield is plugged into the Arduino, right?

If you want to use different pins, you have to make another interface board.

Comment: [link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/A000007/1050-1002-ND/2638990?WT.mc_id=PLA_2638990) I think this is the board i use and i just plug it onto the arduino board. So it means that the port is automatically configured and cannot be changed?

Comment: no, you're wrong, it's not called opensource hardware for nothing. If you read the schematics, you can see that you can change the pins! I've done that with that exact same board and it works.